# What is the Ukrainian equivalent of a community college?

Tags: historical-context, translation, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

At one point in *Voroshilovgrad*, Injured and Herman go from the old airport to what's referred to in the books as the community college dorms.

I'm slightly confused by this translation, since I don't think that Ukraine has an exact equivalent to U.S. community colleges (unless I'm mistaken), and most community colleges in the U.S. at least don't have dorms (admittedly, with a [few exceptions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_community_colleges_in_the_United_States_with_campus_housing)).

What kind of institution is this referring to? Is there an actual institution like this in Luhansk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education_in_Ukraine), there isn’t really an exact equivalent to community college, but the lowest level of accreditation for post-secondary education is the technical school and some graduates of second-level colleges are junior specialists which are degrees which are normally representative of 2.5–3 years’ study as opposed to the bachelor which is 4 years’s study and more comparable to the American bachelor’s degree.

The Ukrainian article on [Luhansk](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA) indicates that it’s home to 5 universities, 14 secondary special institutions and 18 technical schools which would indicate that the community college referred to here is likely a college or technical school producing junior specialists. There doesn’t seem to be much detail about those colleges and technical schools that I can find, but it wouldn’t surprise me to learn that they do have dorms.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education_in_Ukraine#Access_and_affordability): "Trade schools (Technikums), which are analogous to community colleges in the US and award the junior specialist degree".